# How to delete an entity that can be in an "OneToMany"-relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have two entities: a `Person` and an `Address`.

- a `Person` can have an `Address`
- an `Address` can live self-sufficient from a `Person`.

I'have created the relationship like this:

**Address**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="address", cascade={"detach"})
 */
protected $persons;
```

**Person**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="persons", cascade={"detach"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $address;
```

When I now try to delete an `Address` that is related to a `Person` it results, of course, in an "**Integrity constraint violation**". How can I tell doctrine to simply *detach* the `Address` from the `Person`. If tried using `cascade={"detach"}` on both but nothing happens.

Comment: There is a difference between `detach` and `delete` operations (obviously). I assume you want to physically delete the record from database, right?

Comment: Actually I want to delete `Address` physically and to reset the reference in `Person`.

Comment: OK, I added the answer that should be suitable for your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Person:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="persons")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
*/
protected $address;
```

Address:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="address", cascade={"all"})
*/
protected $persons;
```

This setup works perfectly for me. When you delete address, person will get NULL in address_id. Cascade all in Address will also save new persons if you do something like:

```
$address->setPersons(
    array( $person1, $person2 )
) ;
```

Where $person would be:

```
$person1 = new Person() ;
$person1->setName(....) ;
```

In case this doesn't work, please send the code from controller or unit tests. It should be just the most basic code; if you work with address, you just persist address entity. Same for person entity. You don't need to persist both, doctrine will take care of that.

Comment: This would be a very easy solution. :) When I update my code with yours it happens that when I delete an `Address` the `Person` gets deleted too. Argh.

Comment: Try it by removing `cascade={"all"}` or putting `cascade={"persist"}` instead. What is your controller code, maybe you have some error there?

Comment: This brings up the good old *violation* again. :) I've updated the question with remove action of `Address`.

Comment: Just tried it; `cascade={"all"}` has to be removed and the code will work.

Comment: Pretty impressive - it works. And it's so sleek. Awesome. Many thanks for your patience. It's a little awkward: I forgot to update the database after adding the `onDelete`-statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it like this:

```
$id = ...; #some id
$personRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Person'); #entity repository
$em = $this->getDoctine()->getEntityManager();

$person = $personRepository->find($id);
$address = $person->getAddress();
$person->setAddress(NULL); 
$em->remove($address);
$em->flush();
```

Couple of side notes concerning  `$person->setAddress(NULL)`:

- You must call this if you have `CASCADE` constraint for foreign key. Otherwise you will **loose** `Person` record as well.
- If you change constraint to `SET NULL` the line `$person->setAddress(NULL)` is not necessary as it will automatically set the `NULL` value.

Hope this helps....

Comment: This one works fine, when I update the `setAddress()`-method to also accept a `null`-value. I first tried to set the *ORM* to `nullable=true`, which didn't work. This seems like a lot of coding work, when having a lots of "loose" relationships. Many thanks.

Comment: So, we take 2 trips to the DB to delete the row despite the fact that we have the PK of the row in our hand. One to fill in an object so that we can turn around in delete it. Why not just fire off a delete to the DB with the ID?

Comment: You could just delete the `Person` if you have `SET NULL` FK constraint (as pointed out in the second bullet). Otherwise you must first detach `Person` from `Address`...

Answer (score 1):

[jperovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662615/jperovic) solution is working - I dind't tested it, but it sounds good to me. 
What I can suggest to you is, for reduce amount of code and likely errors, to follow one of this streets:

1. ORM BASED - [read more](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)
2. RDBMS BASED - use `ON DELETE SET NULL` directly into foreign key onto your table i.e.

   ```
   CONSTRAINT fk_18ffff524ebd63f2 FOREIGN KEY (canale_id)
     REFERENCES canale (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
   ```

(from postgresql)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer too. The thing is, when using `cascade={"remove"}` both objects get deleted. In this case: no matter which one is deleted the other one should stay. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yes, sorry.. With "remove" all objects related are removed. My fault. I meant "set null". I'll update ;-)

Edit: just updated :)